# (Android) ShareActivity crops space from the title

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to implement a share functionality in my app. But it seems impossible to make a nice title in the activity if I have a scrollable list in there.

Here is a picture that you know what I mean:
[my shareActivity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aht8fb5adq3auza/my%20ShareActivity.jpg)

and this is how it should look like:
[google chromes shareActivity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahapbdn1e8s39yx/Chromes%20ShareActivity.jpg)

The language is not the problem.

This is the way I try it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share"));
```

Did anyone has this kind of problem too and can help me?

Comment: After some try & error I found out that it has something to do with the notification bar or the action bar whether I show them or not. I am trying to show none of them and in some way Android don't like this so much.
But still I don't know how to make it look nice with my approach...